# JS setTimeout get event after delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to translate values if the user is hovering over the element with the mouse for 1.5 seconds. I wrote a little jQuery function, but I don't know how I can verify if the user is over the element after 1.5 seconds.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.search-translate', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() { translate(e, this); }, 1500);
});

function translate(pEvent, pThis)
{
    if(pEvent.currentTarget == ???.currentTarget)
    {
        $.ajax(.....);
    }
}
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: You are losing `this` context in `setTimeout`... `setTimeout(function() { translate(e, this); }.bind(this), 1500);`

Comment: Cancel the timeout in a mouse out handler.

Comment: @nnnnnn Good idea, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet of code....

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', '.search-translate', function(e) {
   var obj=this;
   setTimeout(function() { translate(e, obj); }, 1500);
  });

  function translate(pEvent, pThis)
  {
   alert(pEvent+" : "+pThis);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I mouseover the setTimeout start, if I mouseout the setTimeout event will be canceled.

```
var tTimeout;

function translate(pEl)
{
    ....    
}

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(document).on('mouseover', '.search-translate', function(e) {
        var el = this;

        tTimeout = setTimeout(function() { translate(el); }, 1500);
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '.search-translate', function() {
    clearTimeout(tTimeout);
});
```